# If I counterspell with subtle metamagic, can my counterspell be counterspelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, spell-components, counterspelling

BBEG casts a spell, I counterspell, and the mob has a chance to counterspell my counterspell under normal circumstances, leading to a wasted slot and some hurt from the incoming spell.

If however I cast counterspell with subtle metamagic, am I right in thinking that this counterspell itself cannot be counterspelled as there is no way to identify that i'm casting this spell?

*Subtle casting: "When you cast a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to cast it without any somatic or verbal components."*